# How to make this red button clickable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, particles.js

I'm using bootstrap, CSS, particle.js as my dependencies.
And the custom CSS file has been linked here.
When you apply bootstrap and particle.js my red colour generate password button becomes unclickable as I have seen from chrome dev tool particle.js is running over the button and that's why I cannot click the button please suggest how can I fix this problem.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rowdies:wght@700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:ital@1&display=swap');
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body
{
    background:white;
    margin-top: 10%;
}
.navbar-dark
{
    background-color: #1A237E;
}
#logo
{
    max-height: 50px;
    max-width: 50px;
}
#content
{
    border:2px black ridge;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}
h1
{
    padding-left: 36%;
}
h3
{
    padding-left: 34%;
}
#wel
{
    margin-left: 6%;
    font-family: 'Rowdies', cursive;
}
.align
{
    padding-left: 36%;
}
h3,h6
{
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}
#submit-button
{
    margin-left: 13%;
    ;
}
#particles-js
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
footer
{
    margin-top: 3.6%;
    background-color: yellow;
    color: indigo;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    display: block;
}

#contact
{
    text-align: center;
}
.fa-envelope
{
    color: indigo;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>strong password generator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Depd/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Depd/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./home.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="particles-js"></div>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="#"><img src="./logo.png" alt="logo image" id="logo">Pass Creator</a>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container" id="content">
        <div class="row">
                <h1 id="wel">WELCOME!!!!</h1>
                    <p>
                        <h3>GENERATE  A  STRONG  PASSWORD</h3>
                    </p>
        </div>
        <form action="{% url 'password' %}" method="GET">
            <div class="form-group row align">
                <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label" for="select-number">
                    <h6>Length:</h6>
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-12">
                <input type="number" name="select-number" min="6"  max="20" value="12" selected='selected' placeholder="Length">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <span>
                        <label for="UPPER" class="col-form-label">
                           <h6> UPPER : </h6>
                        </label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="UPPER">
                    </span>
                    &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <span>
                        <label for="specialcharacter" class="col-form-label">
                            <h6>SPECIAL CHARACTER : </h6>
                        </label>
                        <input TYPE="checkbox" name="specialcharacter">
                    </span>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <span>
                        <label for="number" class="col-form-label">
                           <h6>NUMBER : </h6> 
                        </label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="number">
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <label for="unique" class="col-form-label">
                        <h6>Don't create this password for other users</h6> 
                     </label>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="unique">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" role="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" id="submit-button" href="./final.html">Generate Password</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <address>
                        <h5>Address <i class="fa fa-globe"></i></h5>
                        <p>Nayapatti, Near Technopolis,Secor V,Bidhannagar, North 24 Parganas, West Bengal, India 
                        </p>
                    </address>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6" id="contact">
                    <span>
                        <h5>
                            Contact:
                        </h5>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                    <a href="mailto:soumalyabhattacharya6@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i></a>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <i class="fa fa-github fa-lg"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="./particles.js"></script>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
    <script src="./Depd/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./Depd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./Depd/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding `z-index` to the `.container`. I'm guessing because your code is not showing properly.

Comment: Sorry di your solution didn't work

Comment: try changing the `#particles-js` z-index to `-1`. I had a project where I had to use particle.js and had a similar problem. I'm not sure but It seems like the particle division always stays on top ‍♀️ Let me know if that works.

Comment: I added my solution below I actually set the particle.js position as absolute and the container containing the data as position=relative this simple trick worked for me.

Comment: Glad you got sorted. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically add position as absolute on the particle.js so that it is absolutely behind acting as a background. and add position as relative to the container containing the data so that it floats relative to the particle.js layer.

```css
#content
{
    border:2px black ridge;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    position: relative;
}
#particles-js
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please set height of div with id particles-js.

```
#particles-js {
     height:0;
}
```

This div is empty and overlapping the menu bar.
Or You can change position for the div as follows.

```
#particles-js {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: If I add height 0 it would not show only isn't it ?

Comment: We should set position as well